# provisioningProfile conflict during build

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode8

i want to release app using x-code

```
******** has conflicting provisioning settings. ******* is automatically signed,but
provisioning profile ********** has been manually specified.
Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor, or switch 
to manual signing in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
```

I tried a lot, but can't solve it. how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the steps below:

> 1. Select the Target  -- > General --> Signing --> Select the Team (It must the Super account)
> 2. Then select the Build Settings in Target, keep the Development team with the same with Selected team. Set the Provisoning Profile with
>      Automatic and Code Signing Identity with iOS Developer.
> 3. Select the Project -- > Build Settings. Set the Provisoning Profile and Code Signing Identity with Details information

Comment: thanks alot, i'll set all signing to automatic, and its work

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as soon as I updated to Xcode 10, and nothing I did would make Xcode stop looking for the manually specified profile and run automatic code signing.

Here's how I fixed it:

1. Copy the Provisioning Profile identifier from the error message - "provisioning profile [THIS PART] has been manually specified"
2. Control+click on the project.xcodeproj file and select "Show Package Contents"
3. Open the project.pbxproj file in a text editor.
4. Search for the Provisioning Profile identifier and delete it wherever you find PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "[your Provisioning Profile identifier]";
5. Save the project file.
6. Move on with your life.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the Automatic option in Project -> General and In build settings for Provisioning profile select Automatic then Xcode will automatically resolve that issue for you, If not please comment that response here